What's the equality condition of inequality $\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}\rank\begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \geq \rank A + \rank B$?
I know the inequality
$$\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}
\rank\begin{bmatrix}
A & C \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} \geq \rank A + \rank B$$
holds.
But when does the equality hold?
My guess is
$$\rank\begin{bmatrix}
A & C \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} = \rank A + \rank B$$
holds iff
$A$ is a row full rank matrix, or $B$ is a column full rank matrix.
But I have no clue how to prove it.

Number of linear independent columns in the first column part will be the same as that of $A$. For, the second part however, it will be at least the number of linearly independent columns in $B$. Now what about the other dependent columns? This may still be linearly dependent except when $C$ is such that it makes them linearly independent. So, you should check what type of $C$ prevents those columns to be linearly independent. That should be required condition for equality. Note that equality is based on nature of $C$ not $A$ or $B$.

The answer: is the image of $C$ restricted $ker B$ is contained in the image of $A$.

Your guess is off. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&0\ 0&0},,C=\pmatrix{0&0\ 1&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&0\ 0&1}$. In terms of matrices, one necessary and sufficient condition for equality to hold is that $C=AX+YB$ for some matrices $X$ and $Y$.

@user1551 Could you please give me a hint on how to prove this necessary and sufficient condition?

@Galoisgroup Do you mean ${ y \in V' \mid y = C x \land x \in \operatorname{ker} B } \subseteq \operatorname{Im} A$?

Yes, exactly this

Oops, I'm not familiar with Linear Space yet. Is it a necessary and sufficient condition for the equality to hold? @Galoisgroup

I believe that to prove that $C=AX+YB$ is sufficient (and yours is more sufficient to that) you can do row/column transformation from $A$ to $C$ and from $B$ to $C$ and make $C$ to zero. Whether it is necessary... idk.

@KaiserKatze By changing the bases in the domain and codomain of the block matrix, we may assume that $A=\pmatrix{I_r\ &0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0\ &I_s}$ where $r$ and $s$ are the ranks of $A$ and $B$ respectively. The rest should be straightforward.

Denote the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
A & C \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}$$
by $Q$. The matrix $Q$ gives a linear operator $Q\colon V_1\oplus V_2\to W_1\oplus W_2$. Namely $Q(v_1,v_2)=(A v_1+C v_2, B v_2)$. Consider the natural projection $\pi\colon W_1\oplus W_2\to W_2$. We have $\pi(\mathrm{Im}(Q))=\mathrm{Im}B$. So $\mathrm{Im}Q=\mathrm{Im}A+\mathrm{Im}B$ if and only if $\mathrm{Im}Q\cap W_1=\mathrm{Im} A$.
First of all $\mathrm{Im} A\subset\mathrm{Im}Q\cap W_1$. Indeed, $Q(v,0)=(A v, 0)\in W_1$.
Let us compute $\mathrm{Im}Q\cap W_1$. The vector $Q(v_1,v_2)=(A v_1+C v_2, B v_2)$ is contained in $W_1$ iff $v_2\in \mathrm{ker} B$. In this case the vector $Q(v_1,v_2)$ is equal to $(A v_1+C v_2,0)$. This vector is contained in $\mathrm{Im} A$ iff $C v_2\in \mathrm{Im} A$. So our condition is:

If $B v_2=0$ then there is $v_1$ such that $C v_2=A v_1$. Or $$C(\mathrm{ker}B)\subset\mathrm{Im}(A).$$


Sufficiency.
Assume $X = X_0, Y = Y_0$ is the solution of equation $AX+YB=C$.
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  I & -Y_0 \\
  0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  A & C \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  I & -X_0 \\
  0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}
  A & C-Y_0B \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  I & -X_0 \\
  0 & I
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
  A & C-Y_0B-AX_0 \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
  A & 0 \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $I$ is identity,
thus $$\rank\begin{bmatrix}
  A & C \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix} = \rank A + \rank B.$$
Necessity.
Assume
$\rank A=r,
\rank B=s$,
and
$$
P_1 A Q_1
= \begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
P_2 B Q_2
= \begin{bmatrix}
I_s & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $P_1,Q_1,P_2,Q_2$ are invertible.
Notice
$$
A \mapsto P_1 A Q_1, \qquad
B \mapsto P_2 B Q_2, \qquad
C \mapsto P_1 C Q_2, \qquad
X \mapsto Q_1^{-1} X Q_2, \qquad
Y \mapsto P_1 Y P_2^{-1},
$$
we can assume $A = \begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
and $B = \begin{bmatrix}
I_s & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.
In addition,
assume $$C = \begin{bmatrix}
C_1 & C_2 \\
C_3 & C_4
\end{bmatrix},
X = \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 & X_2 \\
X_3 & X_4
\end{bmatrix},
Y = \begin{bmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2 \\
Y_3 & Y_4
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Transform
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  A & C \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 & C_1 & C_2 \\
0 & 0 & C_3 & C_4 \\
0 & 0 & I_s & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\to \begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & C_4 \\
0 & 0 & I_s & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Because $\rank\begin{bmatrix}
  A & C \\
  0 & B
\end{bmatrix} = \rank A + \rank B = r + s$,
there is no way $C_4 \neq 0$, hence $C_4 = 0$.
Now we have $$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
C_1 & C_2 \\
C_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 + Y_1 & X_2 \\
Y_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 & X_2 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
Y_1 & 0 \\
Y_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
that is, $AX+YB=C$ have solutions, such as $X_1 = C_1, X_2 = C_2, Y_1 = 0, Y_3 = C_3$.
